# How does Python / pip handle conflicting transitive dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, python-poetry

Suppose I want to install package `a` which requires the packages `b1` and `b2`. In turn, `b1` requires `c > 1.0.0` and `b2` requires `c < 1.0.0`. So the requirements of `b1` and `b2` cannot be fulfilled at the same time with the same package.

In principle / other programming languages, this is not a problem. One could install two versions of `c` side by side and make sure that `b1` uses another version than `b2`.

However, I'm not sure if pip can install two versions of the same package. My first question is: Can pip install two versions of one package?

My main question is how one actually can deal with that problem. The only ways I can imagine right now is to

1. fork `b1` (or `b2`) and a version of `c` that works for the fork, and upload `b1_forked` and `c_for_b1_forked` to PyPI, or
2. Include the code of `b1` (or `b2`) directly in my project

Both seem more problematic than necessary.

### What I tried

```
>>> import natsort; print(natsort.__file___)
'/home/moose/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/natsort/__init__.py'

$ cd /home/moose/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
$ ls
[... a lot of *.dist-info directories, some .py files, some .so files, ]
[... some directories called like the packages I've installed]
```

So I'm pretty sure this is where Python looks for installed packages and that only one version is installed (although the `*-dist-info` directories confuse me a bit).

[This blog post](https://medium.com/knerd/the-nine-circles-of-python-dependency-hell-481d53e3e025) suggests that there is no good solution for conflicting transitive dependencies at the moment. Do other projects (e.g. poetry) help with that?

Comment: [Pipsi and Pipx may be good places to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500141/python-packages-with-conflicting-dependencies)

Comment: Is this on a windows environment, linux, or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm mainly asking for Linux, but if there are differences I'm also curious.

Answer (score 6):

> In principle / other programming languages, this is not a problem. One could install two versions of `c` side by side and make sure that `b1` uses another version than `b2`.

That's not a solution. If `c` manages a shared resource (console, e.g.) sooner or later `b1` and `b2` will stomp each other input or output via different `c`s and you end up with incorrect input and garbage output.

What you describe is a general problem, not limited to Python or `pip`. The only solution is to change `b1` and/or `b2` to agree on a version of `c`. Either downgrade `b1` to allow `c < 1.0` or upgrade `b2` to allow `c > 1.0`.

> Can `pip` install two versions of one package?

No, and the problem is not in `pip` but in Python: its import system doesn't allow importing from different versions of the same package. You can look at [`mitsuhiko/multiversion`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/multiversion) (Python2-only).

Comment: Well, if `c` never causes side effects (e.g. pure functions) then installing two versions of `c` aside each other is totally fine. As you stated, _shared resources_ cause the problem. Another example why a library developer should think twice about using logging etc...

Comment: Why would shared resources cause problems? If v1 sends "Logging from v1" to the console and v2 sends "Logging from v2" to the console, nothing breaks. If v1 uses a google cloud API v1 and v2 uses a google cloud API v2, nothing breaks.

In an importing model that allows multiple versions (e.g. `nodejs`) there's no difference between two versions of the same library and two different libraries