# Ignore pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict or ResolutionImpossible

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I have built a python module which installs kwikapi==0.4.5 and requests==2.22.0. But kwikapi has requests==2.18.4.

Now when I install and run my package, I am getting error `pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (requests 2.22.0 (/tmp/test_vir3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('requests==2.18.4'), {'kwikapi'})`.

Now if I install requests==2.18.4(pip install requests==2.18.4) and run then the error is `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'requests==2.22.0' distribution was not found and is required by my-pack`.

I can use 2.18.4 instead of 2.22.0 requests to solve this. But this problem again comes if I have same module with different versions in both requests and in kwikapi.

**Is there a way to ignore/solve this error?**

**setup/reproduce**

`Module structure`

```
.
├── my_pack
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = "0.0.1"
setup(
    name="my_pack",
    packages=find_packages("."),
    package_dir={"my_pack": "my_pack"},
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "kwikapi==0.4.5",
        "requests==2.22.0"
    ],
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["my_pack = my_pack:main"]},
)
```

`__init__.py`

```py
def main():
    print("Hey! I ran")
```

`Create python virtual environment and activate`

```sh
$ python3.7 -m venv vir
$ source vir/bin/activate
```

`install`

```
# Go to setup.py file location and do
$ pip install .
```

`Run`

```sh
$ my_pack
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60084441/7976758 In short: you should make your dependencies agree on using transitive subdependencies.

Comment: The above answer is not sufficient. I have a version of torchvision (0.11.2+cu102) and a version of torch (1.11.0a0+git786f946) which work fine together. I can't use my entry point because of this issue. Instead I have to invoke everything via `python -m <mypkg>`. Is there any way to bypass this overzealous check or downgrade it to a warning?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered doing something like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = "0.0.1"
setup(
    name="my_pack",
    packages=find_packages("."),
    package_dir={"my_pack": "my_pack"},
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "kwikapi==0.4.5",
        "requests>=2.18.4,<3"  # Adjusted
    ],
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["my_pack = my_pack:main"]},
)
```