# dependency conflict, featexp 0.0.5 has requirement numpy==1.15.4, pydeck 0.3.0b2 has requirement numpy>=1.16.4

Tags: python, numpy, pip

- pip version: pip 20.0.2
- Python version: Python 3.6.5  Anaconda
- OS: Mac OS X 10.14.5

```
$ pip check
featexp 0.0.5 has requirement numpy==1.15.4, but you have numpy 1.18.2.
```

Then, I change the version of numpy:

```
$ pip install numpy==1.15.4
Collecting numpy==1.15.4
  Using cached numpy-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (24.5 MB)
ERROR: pydeck 0.3.0b2 has requirement numpy>=1.16.4, but you'll have numpy 1.15.4 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.18.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.18.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.18.2
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4
```

But, pydeck 0.3.0b2 has requirement numpy>=1.16.4.

I'm stuck.

Comment: Pinning the dependencies in a distributed library to a single version is not best practice and lead to such problems. You should download the featexp sources, modify `setup.py` and install with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: @KlausD. That makes sense. Thank you for answering!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085201/7976758