# How to Load two different Python Modules whose shared library requirements conflict if set globally

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries

I am working on a project where I need to use two python modules together:

- [PyMesh](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): A Geometry Processing Library
- [PyRep](https://github.com/stepjam/PyRep): A python api interface to the [CoppeliaSim](https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/) robotics simulator.

After following the instructions to [install PyMesh from source](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#download-the-source), I was able to succesfully `import pymesh` with my Python 3.8 interpreter (on Ubuntu 18).

I then downloaded and installed PyRep. This initially didn't work, and gave the error:

```
    ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrep/backend/sim.py in <module>
      1 from .simConst import *
----> 2 from ._sim_cffi import ffi, lib
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import collections
      5 

ImportError: libcoppeliaSim.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The installation instructions for PyRep said this is because I need to ensure that PyRep has access to the shared libraries in my local CoppeliaSim installation, and that I should add the following lines to my .bashrc:

```
export COPPELIASIM_ROOT=EDIT/ME/PATH/TO/COPPELIASIM/INSTALL/DIR
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$COPPELIASIM_ROOT
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=$COPPELIASIM_ROOT
```

Success! I can `import pyrep` without issue. However, if I now import pymesh again, I get an error:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymesh2-0.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/pymesh/Mesh.py in <module>
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
----> 5 import PyMesh
      6 
      7 class Mesh(object):

ImportError: /home/craig/Programs/CoppeliaSim/libtbb.so: file too short
```

By globally setting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at bash login as suggested, I've caused pymesh to search for conflicting shared libraries in the Coppelia-Sim Root folder! (Looking for solutions, I found [an article which condems changing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in .bashrc for exactly this reason](https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180))

How do I resolve this dilemna? PyRep asks me to add a directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but  PyMesh breaks if I do so (though I can get each to work in isolation).

### Attempted Alternatives

I have learned through researching this problem that you can change where a particular shared library looks for dependencies using the `patchelf` command. So I tried just manually tweaking where the offending PyRep `_sim_cffi` library with:

```
patchelf --set-rpath "/home/craig/Programs/CoppeliaSim" ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrep/backend/_sim_cffi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

However, this just leads to transitive dependency errors one level down:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrep/backend/sim.py in <module>
      1 from .simConst import *
----> 2 from ._sim_cffi import ffi, lib
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import collections
      5 

ImportError: libQt5SerialPort.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hi, what about trying the opposite ? (rpath on coppeliaSim)

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading a bit about `pipx` on old posts, it could be a potential solution.

I leave you here some info.

> You can try using [pipx](https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx).
>
> pipx will do all the work of setting up separate virtual environments
> for each application, so that all the applications' dependencies
> remain separate.
>
> If you use virtualenv yourself, you have to switch environments to run
> a different application. pipx handles the environment for you, so you
> don't have to mess with the virtualenvs at all.
>
> From the docs:
>
> > pipx is made specifically for application installation, as it adds
> > isolation yet still makes the apps available in your shell: pipx
> > creates an isolated environment for each application and its
> > associated packages.

*Source: [stackoverflow's @jpyams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955897/14325407)*

Hope this was useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I could think of was to create a virtual environment and use that to install your packages. But the problem will still persist, as the issue lies in the shared path between the two packages. Some things you can try:

- Create a shell script to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, do a pip install for PyRep. Then run the script.

  MyScript.sh

  ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export COPPELIASIM_ROOT=EDIT/ME/PATH/TO/COPPELIASIM/INSTALL/DIR
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$COPPELIASIM_ROOT
   export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=$COPPELIASIM_ROOT

   pip3 install -r requirements.txt
   python3 setup.py install --user
  ```

  Run the script

  ```
   ./MyScript
  ```
- You can also set the environment variable for the command which is run, like below

  MyScript.sh

  ```
   pip3 install -r requirements.txt
   python3 setup.py install --user
  ```

  Run the script

  ```
  $ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:EDIT/ME/PATH/TO/COPPELIASIM/INSTALL/DIR ./MyScript
  ```

The above solutions will ensure that the corresponding LD_LIBRARY_PATH is only set when trying to install PyRep and the subsequent path issues for PyMesh shouldn't arise.