# How can I solve the error No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Tags: python, pip

I tried to create an web application using this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/profile-application-using-python-flask-and-mysql/ but I received this error:

> No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Then I tried to use $ pip install flask-mysqldb command but I got more errors among which

> ERROR: Cannot install flask-mysqldb==0.1.1 and flask-mysqldb==0.2.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
>
> The conflict is caused by:
> flask-mysqldb 0.2.0 depends on mysqlclient
> flask-mysqldb 0.1.1 depends on mysqlclient
>
> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

I do not know what to do, Application Code looks like that:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re
  
  
app = Flask(__name__)
  
  
app.secret_key = 'your secret key'
  
  
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'geekprofile'
  
  
mysql = MySQL(app)
  
  
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (username, password, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return render_template('index.html', msg = msg)
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)
  
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
   session.pop('loggedin', None)
   session.pop('id', None)
   session.pop('username', None)
   return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I'm using the Mariadb database, Python 3.9.2 if it has any importance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955897/13552470